# read.csv and fread produce different results for the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, fread, read.csv

`fread` function from data.table package reads large csv files faster than the `read.cvs` function. But as you can see from the output of a data frame from both routines are different for the "device _id" column (see last 3 digits). Why? Is there a parameter in these functions to read them correctly? Or this is a normal behavior for `fread`? (it reads this datafile 10x faster though).

```
# Read file
p<-fread("C:\\User\\Documents\\Data\\device.csv",sep=", integer64="character" )
> str(p)
         Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 187245 obs. of  3 variables:
         $ device_id   : Factor w/ 186716 levels "-1000025442746372936",..: 89025 96789 140102 123523 45208 118633 32423 22215 54410 81947 ...
         $ phone_brand : Factor w/ 131 levels "E<U+4EBA>E<U+672C>""| __truncated__,"E<U+6D3E>""| __truncated__,..: 52 52 16 10 16 32 52 32 52 14 ...
         $ device_model: Factor w/ 1598 levels "1100","1105",..: 1517 750 561 1503 537 775 753 433 759 983 ...
         - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

> head(p)
                          device_id            brand                     device_model
            1: -8890648629457979026 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                 <U+7EA2><U+7C73>
            2:  1277779817574759137 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                             MI 2
            3:  5137427614288105724 <U+4E09><U+661F>                        Galaxy S4
            4:  3669464369358936369            SUGAR <U+65F6><U+5C1A><U+624B><U+673A>
            5: -5019277647504317457 <U+4E09><U+661F>                    Galaxy Note 2
            6:  3238009352149731868 <U+534E><U+4E3A>                             Mate

# Read file
p<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data\\device.csv",sep=",")

# Convert device_id to character
> p$device_id<-as.character(p$device_id)

> str(p)
    'data.frame':   187245 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ device_id   : chr  "-8890648629457979392" "1277779817574759168" "5137427614288105472" "3669464369358936576" ...
 $ phone_brand : chr  "<U+5C0F><U+7C73>""| __truncated__ "<U+5C0F><U+7C73>""| __truncated__ "<U+4E09><U+661F>""| __truncated__ "SUGAR" ...
 $ device_model: chr  "<U+7EA2><U+7C73>""| __truncated__ "MI 2" "Galaxy S4" "<U+65F6><U+5C1A><U+624B><U+673A>""| __truncated__ ...

    > head(p)
                     device_id            brand                     device_model
        1 -8890648629457979392 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                 <U+7EA2><U+7C73>
        2  1277779817574759168 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                             MI 2
        3  5137427614288105472 <U+4E09><U+661F>                        Galaxy S4
        4  3669464369358936576            SUGAR <U+65F6><U+5C1A><U+624B><U+673A>
        5 -5019277647504317440 <U+4E09><U+661F>                    Galaxy Note 2
        6  3238009352149731840 <U+534E><U+4E3A>                             Mate
```

Comment: I google the codes and it seems those are unicodes for some chinese characters. Are you trying to import chinese brands and devices?

Comment: Try showing the `class()` of each of the columns with `str()` or something. What is the value that's actually in the file? It would be easier to help if you provided a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You probably want to force device_id to be a character value in both cases. It's likely number with `read.csv`.

Comment: As @MrFlick wrote, please provide the files for examination. Also, if you're looking for speed and better control over encoding you should probably try `readr::read_csv`.

Comment: I added structure of data.frames created by both functions (see text above). I do not know how to attache a file for the data. Yes, the "brand" column is in Chinese. But this is irrelevant. What is important is the difference between the device_id values in the left most 3 digits in spite of the fact that in both cases device_id is of same class: factor.  The first line in the csv file is "-8890648629457979026,小米,红米" i.e. "fread" reads the file correctly, but "read.csv" reads it wrongly. "readr::read_csv" converts device_id as double (e.g. -8.890649e+18 instead of -8890648629457979026)

Comment: I'd guess your device_ids exceed the maximum number of significant digits R can represent therefore `read.csv` is loosing information by representing it as floating point value. Please provide the column classes of both data.frames. See `.Machine$double*` components to query more details for your machine. A possible solution would be to read the device_id as character instead of number.

Comment: In the case for "read.csv", the device_id is converted to character format (see the text above). And yet it is still wrong.  > .Machine$double returns NULL. (computer is a Lenovo T530 with 6GB memory x64 laptop). So what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Like teger elegantly discussed the `read.csv` function has a limitation in reading 64 bit numbers. So like `fread`, if the `numerals` argument is defined as "no.loss" `read.cvs` also works. Thanks all the contributors to this question.

```
p<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data\\device.csv",sep=",",encoding="UTF-8", numerals="no.loss" )

> head(p)
              device_id      phone_brand                     device_model
1: -8890648629457979026 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                 <U+7EA2><U+7C73>
2:  1277779817574759137 <U+5C0F><U+7C73>                             MI 2
3:  5137427614288105724 <U+4E09><U+661F>                        Galaxy S4
4:  3669464369358936369            SUGAR <U+65F6><U+5C1A><U+624B><U+673A>
5: -5019277647504317457 <U+4E09><U+661F>                    Galaxy Note 2
6:  3238009352149731868 <U+534E><U+4E3A>                             Mate
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `bit64` library is present, `fread` will automatically use it to correctly read integers that exceed 2^32 - 1.

`read.csv` does not do that, so it suffers from overflow.

This is mentioned in the first paragraph at `?fread`:

> Similar to `read.table` but faster and more convenient. All controls such as `sep`, `colClasses` and `nrows` are automatically detected. `bit64::integer64` types are also detected and read directly without needing to read as character before converting.

You are using the `integer64="character"` option, so they will be detected and read as characters. With `read.table`, they will not be detected and not read as characters. If you want `read.csv` to behave similarly, you will need to use the `colClasses` argument to specify the column you want read as a character during import. By the time it has been read in, it is too late. The overflow has already resulted in lost information, `p$device_id<-as.character(p$device_id)` cannot "undo" the problem.

> Is there a parameter in these functions to read them correctly? Or this is a normal behavior for `fread`?

Yes, `fread` is reading things correctly, this is normal behavior. `read.csv` will take a little more work to read things correctly - you will need to use the `colClassses` argument to read the long integer as a character. And it will still be slower.